Prove that the increase in path length is $\varepsilon \sin \alpha + \cal{O}(\varepsilon^2)$ (Snell's law)
In the diagram below, can you prove that for small $\varepsilon$, $$|AB'| - |AB| = \varepsilon \sin \alpha + \cal{O}(\varepsilon^2).$$
Arnold uses this to derive Snell's law, but I can't prove it.
Note: The unlabeled point at the bottom left should be $B$.  For some reason, the label got cut off.


Update
I tried the Law of Cosines, and got $$|AB'|^2 = |AB|^2 + \varepsilon^2 - 2|AB|\varepsilon \cos (\alpha + \pi/2) \\
|AB'| = \sqrt{(|AB| + \varepsilon)^2 - 2|AB|\varepsilon (1 + \cos (\alpha + \pi/2))} \\ 
|AB'| \approx \sqrt{(|AB| + \varepsilon)^2 - 2|AB|\varepsilon (1 + 1 - (\alpha + \pi/2)^2)}$$ but am unable to take this further.
Arnold's diagram explains that most of the work can be done via some (simple?) auxiliary points; but I am unable to fathom the diagram, and he does not explain it.  (The $\beta$ angles and point $C$ are used later in the problem and should probably be ignored for now.)


@JohnOmielan Thanks for catching that.  For some reason, the $B$ label on the bottom left got cut off.

Using the law of cosines you can figure out what $AB’$ is exactly, then just expand in powers of $\epsilon$ (which in your case simply amounts to differentiating with respect to $\epsilon$ at $\epsilon=0$).

@peek-a-boo I tried Law of Cosines, but couldn't take it very far.  Arnold makes it sound like its a simple geometric conclusion (perhaps constructing some auxiliary points or angles - I couldn't get this to work either).

Note that the Law of cosines can be made to work, as I show in my answer, by also using several other relatively basic properties (e.g., $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha) = -\sin(\alpha)$ that I mention and use). Regarding other methods, one can also extend $BB'$ to the left and join it with the vertical line dropped from $A$ to form a right-angled triangle at a point, call it $C$. Using trigonometric values for lengths in terms of $\alpha$, and the Pythagorean theorem, this can then also derive the last line in my first set of equations. However, it involves quite a bit more work.

For quantities $0<x\ll y$, we can approximate any exponent $(x+y)^p$ using the rule $(x+y)^p = y^p (1+x/y)^p = y^p(1+x/py + O(x^2/y^2))$. Since we stipulate that $x\ll y$, this approximation always gives us something which is accurate and useful. If needed, we can get higher accuracy by using more terms in the taylor approximation of the $(1+r)^p$ function, where $r=x/y$. This can be used to simplify any big-O approximations which invoke addition in a denominator ($p=-1$) or under a square root ($p=1/2$), so in particular it can be applied to the semifinal line you wrote.

Also, as others have identified, the small-angle approximation you used to get your final line is not appropriate. You don't seem to be assuming that $\alpha+\pi/2$ is particularly small, so the approximation you used is excessively ambiguating. Instead you should just use the rule $\cos(\alpha+\pi/2) = -\sin(\alpha)$

Let $f(\epsilon)=|AB’|$, for ease of typing. Then,
\begin{align}
f(\epsilon)^2&=|AB|^2+\epsilon^2-2|AB|\epsilon\cos\left(\alpha+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\tag{$*$}\\
&=|AB|^2+\epsilon^2+2|AB|\sin (\alpha)\cdot\epsilon.
\end{align}
In particular, we have $f(0)=|AB|$: suppose henceforth it is positive.  So, for small enough $\epsilon$, the expression on the right above is actually strictly positive so $f$ is actually a smooth function of $\epsilon$.
By differentiating $(*)$, we get
\begin{align}
2f(\epsilon)f’(\epsilon)&=0+2\epsilon+2|AB|\sin(\alpha)\cdot 1,
\end{align}
So, plugging in $\epsilon=0$, we get
\begin{align}
2|AB|\cdot f’(0)&=0+0+2|AB|\sin(\alpha),
\end{align}
and since $|AB|\neq 0$, we can divide to obtain $f’(0)=\sin(\alpha)$. Since $f$ is a smooth function, we can now apply Taylor’s theorem to deduce
\begin{align}
f(\epsilon)&=f(0)+\epsilon\cdot f’(0)+ \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2),
\end{align}
i.e
\begin{align}
|AB’|&=|AB|+\epsilon\sin(\alpha)+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2),
\end{align}
as desired.

Note that since we only want the first order expansion, it turns out in this specific case to be quite easy to carry out the above (‘implicit’) differentiation. In this regard, the result is quite trivial.
In general, if you want the higher order terms in the expansion, then you’re better off writing
\begin{align}
|AB’|&=\sqrt{|AB|^2+\epsilon^2+2|AB|\sin (\alpha)\cdot\epsilon}\\
&=|AB|\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{2\sin(\alpha)}{|AB|}\epsilon+\frac{\epsilon^2}{|AB|^2}\right)},
\end{align}
and then using the binomial expansion for $\sqrt{1+\xi}$ with $|\xi|<1$. As a good exercise in calculus, figure out the coefficient of $\epsilon^2$ using this approach, and as a bonus, carry out the implicit differentiation above once again to figure out $f’’(0)$ and compare results.

As suggested by peek-a-boo's comment, and as indicated in what you've tried yourself, using the Law of cosines, along with $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \alpha\right) = -\sin(\alpha)$, gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lvert AB'\rvert^2 & = \lvert AB\rvert^2 + \varepsilon^2 - 2\varepsilon\lvert AB\rvert\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \alpha\right) \\
\lvert AB'\rvert^2 - \lvert AB\rvert^2 &= 2\varepsilon\lvert AB\rvert\sin\alpha + 
 \varepsilon^2 \\
(\lvert AB'\rvert - \lvert AB\rvert)(\lvert AB'\rvert + \lvert AB\rvert) &= 2\varepsilon\lvert AB\rvert\sin\alpha + \varepsilon^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Since $\angle ABB'$ is the largest angle in $\triangle ABB'$, then $\lvert AB'\rvert$ is the largest side length. Using this and the triangle inequality, we get for some real $0 \lt k \lt 1$ that
$$\lvert AB\rvert \lt \lvert AB'\rvert \lt \lvert AB\rvert + \epsilon \;\to\; \lvert AB'\rvert = \lvert AB\rvert + k\varepsilon \;\to\; \lvert AB'\rvert + \lvert AB\rvert = 2\lvert AB\rvert + k\varepsilon$$
Also, by the sum of an infinite geometric series, for any real $\lvert x\rvert \lt 1$, we have
$$\frac{1}{1 + x} = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + \ldots$$
Note that if $\lvert x\rvert$ is much less than $1$, then just a few terms on the RHS are sufficient to get a close approximation of $\frac{1}{1 + x}$. Using these $2$ results in the first set of equations gives that
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(\lvert AB'\rvert - \lvert AB\rvert)(2\lvert AB\rvert + k\varepsilon) &= 2\varepsilon\lvert AB\rvert\sin\alpha + \varepsilon^2 \\
\lvert AB'\rvert - \lvert AB\rvert &= \frac{2\varepsilon\lvert AB\rvert\sin\alpha}{2\lvert AB\rvert + k\varepsilon} + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2\lvert AB\rvert + k\varepsilon} \\
 &= \frac{2\lvert AB\rvert\varepsilon\sin\alpha}{2\lvert AB\rvert\left(1 + \frac{k\varepsilon}{2\lvert AB\rvert}\right)} + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2\lvert AB\rvert + k\varepsilon} \\
 &= \varepsilon\sin\alpha\left(\frac{1}{1 + \frac{k\varepsilon}{2\lvert AB\rvert}}\right) + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2\lvert AB\rvert + k\varepsilon} \\
 &= \varepsilon\sin\alpha\left(1 - \frac{k\varepsilon}{2\lvert AB\rvert} + O(\varepsilon^2)\right) + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2\lvert AB\rvert + k\varepsilon} \\
 &= \varepsilon\sin\alpha - \frac{k\sin\alpha(\varepsilon^2)}{2\lvert AB\rvert} + O(\varepsilon^3) + \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2\lvert AB\rvert + k\varepsilon} \\
 &= \varepsilon\sin\alpha + O(\varepsilon^2)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Alternatively, similar to what is suggested at the end of peek-a-boo's answer, by completing the square and using Newton's generalized binomial theorem, we get from the Law of cosines equation that
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lvert AB'\rvert^2 & = \lvert AB\rvert^2 + 2\varepsilon\lvert AB\rvert\sin\alpha + \varepsilon^2 \\
\lvert AB'\rvert^2 & = (\lvert AB\rvert^2 + 2\varepsilon\lvert AB\rvert\sin\alpha + \varepsilon^2\sin^2\alpha) - \varepsilon^2\sin^2\alpha + \varepsilon^2 \\
\lvert AB'\rvert^2 & = (\lvert AB\rvert + \varepsilon\sin\alpha)^2 + \varepsilon^2(1 - \sin^2\alpha) \\
\lvert AB'\rvert^2 & = (\lvert AB\rvert + \varepsilon\sin\alpha)^2\left(1 + \frac{\varepsilon^2(1 - \sin^2\alpha)}{(\lvert AB\rvert + \varepsilon\sin\alpha)^2}\right) \\
\lvert AB'\rvert & = (\lvert AB\rvert + \varepsilon\sin\alpha)\sqrt{1 + \frac{\varepsilon^2(1 - \sin^2\alpha)}{(\lvert AB\rvert + \varepsilon\sin\alpha)^2}} \\
\lvert AB'\rvert & = (\lvert AB\rvert + \varepsilon\sin\alpha)\left(1 + \frac{\varepsilon^2(1 - \sin^2\alpha)}{2(\lvert AB\rvert + \varepsilon\sin\alpha)^2} + O(\epsilon^4)\right) \\
\lvert AB'\rvert & = \lvert AB\rvert + \varepsilon\sin\alpha + \epsilon^2\left(\frac{(\lvert AB\rvert + \varepsilon\sin\alpha)(1 - \sin^2\alpha)}{2(\lvert AB\rvert + \varepsilon\sin\alpha)^2}\right) + O(\epsilon^4) \\
\lvert AB'\rvert - \lvert AB\rvert & = \varepsilon\sin\alpha + O(\epsilon^2) \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
